# How do I calculate number of multiplication, exponential, and pairing operations in a cryptographic algorithm (signcryption/unsigncryption)?

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, authenticated-encryption

I have been working on signcryption scheme and its security proof. I want to compute the efficiency in terms of number of scalar multiplication operation, number of exponential operations, and number of bilinear pairing operation. I am comparing it with other schemes as well. I think I am missing out some information regarding point scalar multiplication and couldn't figure how should I count the number of multiplication operation. For example if U[image: signcryption step] in the figure below, I see only 2 multiplication operations U1=r1P2 and U2=r1QA. Is it correct? For the reference, I am looking into [Heterogeneous hybrid signcryption for multimessage and multi-receiver](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0184407&type=printable).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you are working from [Heterogeneous hybrid signcryption for multi-message and multi-receiver](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5590946/) by Niu et al (it would've been useful for you to include this information). In this case the value $sk_A$ is an element of $G_1$ and so all $n$ of the operations $S_i=(r_1+h_i)sk_A$ are also scalar multiplications.

This gives a total of $n+2$ scalar multiplications in $G_1$; $2n$ pairing computations at step 2, and $2n$ exponentiations in $G_2$ (also at step 2).

Comment: Thank you for highlighting. Yes I am working from Heterogeneous hybrid signcryption for multimessage and multi-receiver by Niu et. al and have included this information now. I understand the pairing and exponentiation operations however, regarding multiplication operation, do we consider all those elements which are in G1?

Comment: Yes we consider all expressions that are elements of $G_1$ preceded by an element of $Z_q^*$ as requiring a scalar multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much.